# Generate homeTeam/awayTeam pairs in League Manager application

Tags: java, random

I want to create random pairs of teams to generate matches. A team cannot play with itself and the same match cannot be played. There are 16 teams 2 rounds, 15 matches each round. I have a fixtures list, a teams list and a matches list. My question is how do I create random pairs?
Here is the code I wrote so far for this method:

```
public void generateFixtures() {

    List<Match> fixtureMatches = new ArrayList<Match>();

    for(int i = 1; i<=NUMBER_OF_FIXTURES; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<4; j+=2) {
            Random rand = new Random();

            int t1 = rand.nextInt(15) + 0;
            int t2 = rand.nextInt(15) + 0;
            if(t2==t1) {
                t2 = rand.nextInt(15)+0;

            }
            SQLiteDatabase.insertInMatch(i, teams.get(t1).getTeamName(), teams.get(t2).getTeamName());

            Match m = new Match(teams.get(t1), teams.get(t2));
            fixtureMatches.add(m);
        }
        Fixture f = new Fixture(i, fixtureMatches);
        League.getInstance().fixtures.add(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a homework question or a project question? If so, please read the stack overflow content guidelines.

Comment: What IS your question anyway?

Comment: How to actually create random pairs without them re appearing!???

Comment: I feel like this is a homework so I will give you a clue [Collections.Shuffle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List,%20java.util.Random))

Comment: @CowboyFarnz how did you get a link to the Java 6 API? Java 7 I do understand... but 6? Also, it should be `shuffle`, not `Shuffle` =)

Comment: Alright @Turing85 =) for you my friend, [Collections.shuffle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-)

Comment: @MariosM Your `+ 0` for both `t1` and `t2` seems pretty pointless.